# Sliding boxes jump up and down when moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code that Ive been working with and for the life of me, I cant figure out why this is happening. When you click and drag a box from left to right, the rest slide to fill the open spot as designed. When this happens the remaining boxes drop down and than back up when i drop the box Ive clicked and dragged. Is there a way to keep everything on the same level/line as the box being moved?

```js
$( function() {
       $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
       $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
      } );
```

```css
 #sortable { list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid black;
     }

              #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
     padding: 0.4em;
     padding-left: 1.5em;
     font-size: 1.4em;
     height: 128px;
     width: 150px;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 5px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     background-color: #BF55EC;
     }
     
              #sortable li span { position: absolute;
       margin-left: -1.3em;
     }
  
      .topper {
  
  padding-top: 100px; 
       }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="topper">
  <ul id="sortable">
   <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle HERE:](https://jsfiddle.net/exufk5b2/)
Any help would be grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change `display:inline-block` to `display:block` and add `float:left`, you get the same layout, but the jumping no longer happens.

I don't know *why* they're jumping with the `inline-block`, but this will fix it.

```js
$( function() {
       $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
       $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
      } );
```

```css
 #sortable { list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid black;
     }

              #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
     padding: 0.4em;
     padding-left: 1.5em;
     font-size: 1.4em;
     height: 128px;
     width: 150px;
     display: block;
         float: left;
     padding: 5px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     background-color: #BF55EC;
     }
     
              #sortable li span { position: absolute;
       margin-left: -1.3em;
     }
  
      .topper {
  
  padding-top: 100px; 
       }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="topper">
  <ul id="sortable">
   <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, something so simple that's been troubling me all day.

Comment: @whisk, Just to let you know, they are going down because sortable and draggable functions create a ghost element and this element is placing at the top of the div so it push others element down. I dont know if i was clear

Comment: one way to check it is to drag one box, then hit f8 to pause all scripts executions and then using the developer console check the space that creates the ghost element

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz That make it more clear. Thank you for further  explaining it. Did not know f8 would do that! +1

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz What browser are you using for that `F8` trick?

Comment: @JakeParis Chrome